# Cannot create Ignite-project

Tags: windows, react-native

I am trying to create an Ignite project, but I only get a failure. Do you know why I get a failure? I have installed programs for creating a React-Active-project and these are working fine, I can create a normal React-Active-project. It would be nice to get a solution for this.

I am using Windows 10

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm>ignite new project
� Setting project on FIRE! �
module.js:327
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:974:3
```

Comment: Problem solved. I needed to add 'C:\tools\python2' to path -environmental variable and reinstall all programs. Now it works.