# React Native command not working

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

I am new to `React Native` and starting my first project as per the [Getting started](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) document on `Windows`. I have installed `node` and `python2`. I've also installed the `react-native-cli` using `npm`. But Whenever i am trying to run `react-native init firstProject`

I always receive this error:

```
/bin/sh: /c/Program Files/nodejs/../../Users/Mahesh/AppData/Local/Yarn/config/global/node_modules/.bin/react-native: No such file or directory
```

I also installed `Yarnpkg` from its official site but still getting the same issue. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `C:\Program Files\nodejs` and `C:\tools\python2` in PATH-environmental variable?
I had same kind of problems in the past: [Cannot create Ignite-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233568/cannot-create-ignite-project)